# Show that if $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are subharmonic

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to solve the following example but I can not. This example is:

Show that if $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are subharmonic, then so is $\max \{f(z), g(z)\}$.

Previously thank you for the help

Comment: Mean value property. A function is subharmonic if and only if the value at a point $z_0$ is smaller than or equal to the average of the values on each small enough sphere centered at $z_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h=\max(f,g)$. You should check two properties of $h$:

1. Upper semicontinuity. Indeed, the set $\{z:h(z)<c\}$ is the intersection of the sets $\{z:f(z)<c\}$ and $\{z:g(z)<c\}$, which are open because $f$ and $g$ are upper semicontinuous.
2. Sub-mean-value property. Given $z$, pick one of functions $f,g$ which agrees with $h$ at $z$. Use the sub-mean-value property of that function. Replacing it with $h$ in the integral can only increase the integral.